# Condtitional Validation rules in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-validation

I have a problem in custom validation rules in Yii. I have some fields like `day1s`, `day1e`, `day2s`, `day2e` etc. I want to check whether these attributes have the same value stored in my db or not before creating a new record. And also check for different userid. If a value already exists I want to generate an error and prompt the user to change the value. I figured to do something like this:

```
 array('day1s, day1e, day2s etc','unique','message'=>'day1s is already exist, please change'),
```

This kinda work but I want to modify it. The default value of this is `"00:00"` and if I put this rule then every time I will go and create a new record it generates the error, except the first time. I want to ignore that when `day1s==00:00`. And also if the user changes(in my occasion the user is SchoolID). I'm having trouble wrapping around my head on how to do that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to check if `day1s` is unique or not and..? what else exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add allowEmpty in rule:

```
array('day1s, day1e, day2s etc','unique','message'=>'day1s is already exist, please change', 'allowEmpty'=>true),
```

In controller before validation add this code:

```
if($model->day1s == "00:00") {
   $model->day1s = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being so late to answer. In controller you mean in my action Create?Before `$model->save`?I tried that but it doesn't seem to work. I figured to make a function in my model like this:

```
public function unique() {       
 if ($this->day1s == "00:00" || $this->day1s == "0:00") {

       $this->day1s='';//here it seems to work for the 00:00
 } else {
     //but my rule gets ignored now for any other values. What can I add here to make it work?
 }
```

Also sorry for posting an answer instead of editing my question.

I figured it out eventually: my rules are like this:

```
array('day1s,day1e, day2s, day2e, day3s, day3e, day4s, day4e, day5s, day5e, day6s, day6e, day7s, day7e','unique','message'=>'This already exist, please change', 'allowEmpty'=>true,
                 'criteria' => array(
                 'condition' => 'schoolid=:schoolid',
                 'params' => array(':schoolid' => $this->schoolid))
               ),
```

and my controller is like this:

```
if ($model->day1s == "00:00" || $model->day1s == "0:00") {
    $model->day1s='';//for custom validation rule 'unique'
                    } 
if ($model->day1e == "00:00" || $model->day1e == "0:00") {
                            $model->day1e='';
                    }
 .....
 if($model->validate()){
        if($model->save())
                    $this->redirect('admin');}
    }
```

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: yes it seems fine! I haven't test it thoroughly but it seems legit! thank you very much!

Comment: I just checked it. In update it works fine but when I create a new one it seems to ignore the rules. I think it's strange. I used the same code both on actionUpdate and actionCreate.